# VB Access form is not showing all records against a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

[image]
I have a query which return 98 records but when i try to replace it to a record source of a form it return  92 or 94 records and sometime it shows 98 records.
I don't know what is the issue.

```
SELECT ts1.Id, ts1.Narration, ts1.Mode, ts1.ChequeNo, ts1.Dated, 
       tcs.CustomerID, tcs.Name, ts1.Debit, ts1.Credit, 
       (IIf((select Sum([Debit])-Sum([Credit]) from tblTransactions 
             where cDate(Dated) < cDate(ts1.Dated) and AccountId='1010592'
               and IsDeleted=false) Is Null,
              0,
             (select Sum([ts.Debit])-Sum([ts.Credit]) from tblTransactions ts
              where cDate(ts.Dated) < cDate(ts1.Dated) and ts.AccountId='1010592'
              and ts.IsDeleted=false )) + 
        IIf((select Sum([ts2.Debit])-Sum([ts2.Credit]) from tblTransactions ts2 
             where cDate(ts2.Dated) = cDate(ts1.Dated) and ts2.Id<ts1.Id  
               and ts2.AccountId='1010592' and ts2.IsDeleted=false ) Is Null, 
             0, 
            (select Sum([ts3.Debit])-Sum([ts3.Credit]) from tblTransactions ts3 
             where cDate(ts3.Dated) = cDate(ts1.Dated) and ts3.Id<ts1.Id 
               and ts3.AccountId='1010592' and ts3.IsDeleted=false )) +
            ts1.Debit - ts1.Credit) AS Balance 
FROM tblTransactions AS ts1 
INNER JOIN tblCustomers AS tcs ON ts1.AccountId = tcs.CustomerID 
WHERE tcs.CustomerID = '1010592' 
  AND cDate(Dated) between cdate('01-Mar-20') AND cdate('20-Jun-20') 
  AND ts1.IsDeleted = false  
ORDER BY cDate(Dated) asc, Id asc
```

Comment: Without your secret query, we can't do much.

Comment: please check above query..

Comment: Please show how you *replace it to a record source of a form*.

Comment: @Parfait please check screen shot .. this function is called against button click event

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no issue with your SQL syntax, simply add `Requery` as it is not enough to simply change the SQL in a form's recordsource. You have to actually re-run the query adjustment.

```sql
Me.Form.RecordSource = ledgerqry
Me.Form.Requery
```

Comment: but its some time occurs when i run same query in query design view via sql ..

Comment: Don't know how to help you further without data for reproducible example. We just have to take your word for it! If query *sometimes* return different results it may be underlying data changes. Nonetheless, you still need `.Requery` for form to adjust to updated SQL results.

Comment: However, your problem is not quite clear as posted SQL has hard-coded values for dates and accounts but VBA query is concatenating variables. Be sure values are **exactly** the same for comparison of results. SQL will not just randomly change results with same exact syntax and parameters.